# How to drop HTTP request on non-existing URL with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, servlet-filters, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a webserver on AWS Beanstalk. The log file shows there are quite some HTTP requests to URLs that do not exist on my webserver. Those requests cause Spring Boot to forward the requests to `/error`, for which I have a controller to process.

Those URLs are

- `/hedwig.cgi`
- `/system.ini`
- `/upgrade_handle.php`
- `/board.cgi`
- `/shell`
- `/azenv.php`

Does it mean someone is trying to attack my website? How can I configure Spring Boot or Beanstalk to match those URLs and drop the request so that they do not reach to my controller handling `/error`?